# Using srcset in Vuetify

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, webp, srcset

My `webp` images are not loading in Safari and Edge, so I want to use srcset to use the `png` variant instead if the browser can't load the `webp` file. Currently this is how I define my image:

```
  <img
    :srcset="`${require('../../assets/art/blob-right-side.webp')} ${require('../../assets/art/blob-right-side.png')}`"
    :src="require('../../assets/art/blob-right-side.webp')"
    class="hidden-sm-and-down"
    height="500"
    width="217"
    style="position: absolute; top: 300vh; right: 0;"
  />
```

But my browser (Chrome) returns the following errors:

> Failed parsing 'srcset' attribute value since it has an unknown descriptor.
>
> Dropped srcset candidate
> "/images/blob-bottom-desktop.webp?92a59c3833d65ecd5913e9d37354bcc8"

Can anyone explain to me why this isn't working? I can't find much information about it.

Answer (score 1):

Possible you missed comma between values

```
:srcset="`${require('../../assets/art/blob-right-side.webp')}, ${require('../../assets/art/blob-right-side.png')}`"
```

And I don't see any rules for resolution switching

```
:srcset="`${require('../../assets/art/blob-right-side.webp')}, ${require('../../assets/art/blob-right-side.png')}` 1.5x"
```